# Best way to represent nested resources that has two different type (entities) owners in REST APIs?

Tags: json, rest, api

Suppose I have a entity called `Appointment`. This entity represents an medical appointment between one `Doctor` and one `Patient`.

To create a new `Appointment`, I send somethind like:

`POST /appointments`

```
{
  "doctorId": 98173821,
  "patientId": 2138212,
  ... omitted for brevity
}
```

Works well.

As you can see, this object is nested with two other resources (`Patient` and `Doctor`)

Imagine that logged `Patient` (using his JWT Token) want to see his history of `Appointments`.

Today, I do that sending a request to:

`GET /patients/2138212/appointments?page=1&size=2&startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-08-01`

*(please, feel free to criticize)*

as this is a history, there's no need to retrieve the whole `Appointment` objects. The response retrieves only basic informations about the `Appointments`. The response looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1566216359,
  "transactionId": "6eed92831cad128",
  "data": {
    "appointments": [
      {
        "id": 6372,
        "doctorId": 98173821,
        "date": "2019-01-01"
      },
      {
        "id": 6985,
        "doctorId": 98173821,
        "date": "2019-02-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, what if the `Patient` select an specific `Appointment` in the front-end and the detailed information about this specific `Appointment` needs to be shown? What is the best way to model a REST endpoint like this?

My options:

- `GET /patients/2138212/appointments/6372`
- `GET /appointments/6372`

The first one looks nice and follow up REST patterns on nested resources, since can represent that the `Appointment` 6372 belongs to the `Patient` 2138212.

The second one doesn't provide readability. I mean, looking at the resource, I don't know who owns this `Appointment`. That's why I prefer the first approach.

Now, going down the road, also, the `Doctor` has to see the history of his Appointments.

Today, I do that sending a request to:

`GET /doctors/98173821/appointments?page=1&size=2&startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-08-01`

*(please, feel free to criticize)*

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1566216359,
  "transactionId": "6eed92831cad321",
  "data": {
    "appointments": [
      {
        "id": 6372,
        "patientId": 2138212,
        "date": "2019-01-01"
      },
      {
        "id": 6985,
        "patientId": 2138212,
        "date": "2019-02-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, what if the `Doctor` select an specific `Appointment` in the front-end and the detailed information about this specific `Appointment` needs to be shown? What is the best way to model a REST endpoint like this?

My options:

- `GET /doctors/98173821/appointments/6372`
- `GET /appointments/6372`

The questions I have:

1. How to represent a nested resource that has "two owners"? There is a better approach than this I point out on that question?
2. To the history of `Appointments`, I've been suggested to do `/appointments/doctors/{doctorId}` and `/appointments/patients/{patientId}`, which I heavily disagree, since the `Doctor` and the `Patient` **owns** the `Appointment`, **not the opposite**. What you suggest?

Comment: Questions regarding which URI styles to use are in general primarily opinion-based and as such off-topic on SO. Next, a URI itself is a pointer to a resource and a client should NOT attempt to deduce any semantics from the URI. A server may hint a clint on the purpose of such a URI via link relation names. Further, nesting sub-resources may seem great as all of the data can be set in a single response, though you basically bypass caching of those sub-resources. Ideally you just provide a client with links to the respective appointments which they can invoke if interested

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

```
GET /patients/2138212/appointments/6372
GET /appointments/6372
GET /5877971d-4f91-4297-9995-94f560190463
```

All three of those spellings are *fine*.  From the point of view of a REST client, the URI is just an opaque sequence of bytes that can be used as a cache key.

Choosing a spelling for a URI is a lot like choosing a spelling for a variable name -- the machines don't care; you can choose any spelling you like that is convenient.

Furthermore, REST doesn't particularly care how you organize your domain model into resources, aka "documents".  The "doctor's view of appointment 6372" is not necessarily the same *resource* as "the patient's view of appointment 6372"; there are trade offs to consider there.

Example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557129/best-way-to-represent-nested-resources-that-has-two-different-type-entities-ow
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/57557129?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

> To the history of Appointments, I've been suggested to do /appointments/doctors/{doctorId} and /appointments/patients/{patientId}, which I heavily disagree, since the Doctor and the Patient owns the Appointment, not the opposite. What you suggest?

The hierarchy of path segments in a URI need not imply "ownership".  Again, from the perspective of a REST client, there is no relation between `/X/Y` and `/X/Y/Z` -- they are *different* identifiers, and therefore *different* resources.

There's no fundamental difference between

```
/appointments/patients/{patientId}
/patients/{patientId}/appointments
```

We normally prefer the latter, not because it is "better" in an of itself, but because it can be more convenient when using relative references to identify another resource identifier hierarchy relative to the position of this one.

```
/appointments/patients/{patientId} + .. -> /appointments/patients
/patients/{patientId}/appointments + .. -> /patients/{patientId}
```